# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, intellij-idea, драйвер

На одном проекте подключенный драйвер работает. На другом - нет - выводит эту ошибку. Прочитал, что может быть несоответствие версии драйвера. Но как узнать какая версия требуется?

В обоих случаях подключен драйвер как библиотека и компилится в gradle так:

> compile files('libs/ojdbc8')

Comment: JAR файл с драйвером отсутствует в classpath

Comment: Но в обоих gradle указано одинаково - compile files('libs/ojdbc8') Сам драйвер подключен как библиотека. На другом проекте работает. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: В classpath путь, включая имя файла

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Я бы перепроверил, есть ли сам файл libs/ojdbc8 на той машине, где не работает и classpath на наличие правильного пути к этому файлу. Нет ли дубликатов в classpath? И как Вы запускаете свое приложение?

Answer (score 1):

1) Возможно не соответствует версия java и версию драйвера, если вы используете jdk 1.7, то с драйвером ojdbc8 могут быть проблемы

2) Проверить наличие драйвера, попробовать использовать [jar](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html) с официального сайта.

3) Если oracle установлен не у вас на компьютере, то необходимо проверить соединение, бывает когда java не может достучаться до базы, то пишет что соответствующего драйвера не найдено.

4) Узнать версию oracle можно через запрос

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION
```